Unable to add new sibling maven module as dependency
I created a new maven module (helper) under same parent in the project and need it as dependency in another sibling module under same parent (dal-commons). The new module is obviously not present in Artifactory and I need it for local development and unless its developed and merged, it won't be there in Artifactory as well.
I added like this, as usual with any dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>helper</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

On running mvn clean install even with -U, I am getting this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dal-commons: Could not
resolve dependencies for project
com.parent:dal-commons:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could
not be resolved: com.parent:helper:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could
not find artifact com.parent:helper:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT in snapshots
(https://artifactory..com/libs-snapshot)

My development is just stalled due to this.

Are all these modules in the same multi-module project? Did you build them from the top of the project?

Thanks for your comment. All are in same module, and getting built from root pom in same directory. Ultimately, what passed is I stopped using clean, did mvn install -pl helper first and then built from root. That was strange as root should have build everything, and don't encounter such issues normally.

Ultimately, what passed is I stopped using clean, did mvn install -pl helper first and then built from root. That was strange as root should have built everything, and don't encounter such issues normally.

Which means that you have some other, yet uncovered problem in your multi-module project.

Yes, sometimes we dont have enuogh time to even look. You are right, that shouldnt have been the case.
